# Graph Union with Color Properties Kept

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have generated the two graphs g1 and g2 below in a **separate** Mathematica notebook with the node colors as shown.

I then would like to copy the two graphs into a **new** Mathematica notebook and take their graph union; that is GraphUnion[g1,g2,VertexLabels->Automatic]; however, the graph union loses the original node colors and only produces the default grey nodes. Any recommendations?

```
edges1 = {NS <-> N1, NS <-> N2, N2 <-> N3, N3 <-> N1};
edges2 = {NS <-> S1, S1 <-> S3, S2 <-> N2, N2 <-> NS};
g1 = Graph[edges1, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> {NS | N1 | N2 -> Red, N3 -> Blue}]
g2 = Graph[edges2, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  VertexSize -> 0.2, 
  VertexStyle -> {S1 | S2 | S3 -> Yellow}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not use Graph much at all. But playing with it, it looks like styling is lost when making union.

A workaround meanwhile is to do this

```
edges1 = {NS <-> N1, NS <-> N2, N2 <-> N3, N3 <-> N1};
edges2 = {NS <-> S1, S1 <-> S3, S2 <-> N2, N2 <-> NS};
vs1 = {NS | N1 | N2 -> Red, N3 -> Blue};
vs2 = {S1 | S2 | S3 -> Yellow};
g1 = Graph[edges1, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> vs1]
g2 = Graph[edges2, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> vs2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
GraphUnion[g1, g2, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> Join[vs1, vs2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e need to apply styles manually again.  This seems like a feature limitation. May be submit feature request to WRI on this by emailing  support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[grUnion]
grUnion = GraphUnion[##, 
    Normal@GroupBy[Join @@ (Options /@ {##}), First -> Last, Apply[Union]]] &;

grUnion[g1, g2]
```

[image]

You can add new options and/or replace existing one using `Graph[grUnion[g1,g2], options]`:

```
Graph[grUnion[g1, g2],
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> {Alternatives @@ VertexList[g1] -> White},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: very clever kglr ... I like the node labels inside; many thanks again!